# Python adding Integers in a string

Tags: python

Im getting the error:

```
>>> sum_digits(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    sum_digits(123)
  File "D:/Python/Final/#4.py", line 4, in sum_digits
    for i in n:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

---

```
def sum_digits(n):
   s = 0
   for i in n:
      s += n 
return s
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. BTW, error message and the code does not match: `for i in int(n)`, `for i in n`

Comment: sum_digits(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    sum_digits(123)
  File "D:/Python/Final/#4.py", line 4, in sum_digits
    for i in n:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the number to `str` (not `int`) and iterate it:

```
def sum_digits(n):
   s = 0
   for i in str(n):
      s += int(i)
   return s
```

usage:

```
>>> sum_digits(123)
6
```

Using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
    # OR  return sum(map(int, str(n)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your are passing an `int` to your function, which you cannot iterate over.

I suggest the solution

```
>>> n = 123
>>> sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
6
```

Comment: Even though this is a good one-liner I would upvote otherwise, this person seems to be a beginner who is just experimenting with the language. This syntax would seem unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `i` to range over the *digits* of `n`, you'd need something like:

```
for i in [int(x) for x in str(n)]:
```

Or, you could just pass `"123"` instead of `123` to `sum_digits`, which the title of your post suggests is what you actually mean to do.  Of course, then you'd need to convert each character to its numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over an int but you can still do it without casting to `str`:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    n, i = divmod(n, 10)
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, 10)
        i += r
    return i
```

Demo:

```
In [2]:  sum_digits(123456789)
Out[2]: 45

In [3]:  sum_digits(123)
Out[3]: 6

In [4]:  sum_digits(100)
Out[4]: 1
```

It does not make much sense to convert from int to str then back to int again.